# Как узнать если дата уже прошла?

Tags: php, дата

```
$date1 = "2019-08-27 13:46:35";
$date2 = "2019-08-26 13:26:38";

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

дата 1 - нынешняя дата
дата 2 - созданая дата

---

Код уравнивает две даты и выводит разницу
если еще остался 1 день то покажет 1 
если просрочена на 1 то вернет также 1

Как сделать что если дата просрочена возвращать сроку например просрочена?

Comment: Не использовать `abs`?

Answer (score 2):

Вам лучше использовать стандартные инструменты, доступные в PHP, как-то DateTime и DateInterval, так как ваши рассчеты дат не учитывают ни високосные года, ни разное количество дней в месяцах:

```
 $date1 = new DateTime("2019-08-27 13:46:35");
 $date2 = new DateTime("2019-08-26 13:26:38");
 echo $date1->diff($date2)->format("%y years, %m months, %d days") . PHP_EOL;
 echo 'Дата прошла?: ' . (($date2 > $date1) ? 'да' : 'нет') . PHP_EOL;
```